# Simultaneously solve N-queens and no-3-in-line

Tags: grid, fastest-code, chess

An intriguing [MathsSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4642059/357390) asked if there were large [N-queens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133736/110698) solutions where [no three queens lie on a line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203607/110698). That question's body included the unique 4×4 solution up to symmetries

```
. Q . .
. . . Q
Q . . .
. . Q .
```

and noted that there are no solutions for 5×5 to 7×7 because of knight lines. However, [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) over there then wrote [some code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4642059.java) and found solutions from 8×8 to 16×16, counting all of them in the process:
$$\begin{array}{c|cc} N&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\\hline \text{up to symmetries}&1&0&0&0&1&4&5&12&53&174&555&2344&8968\\ \text{all}&2&0&0&0&8&32&40&96&410&1392&4416&18752&71486 \end{array}$$
I find these restricted solutions quite interesting. Here is a 40×40 solution:

```
. . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . .
Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q
. . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

But my formulation of the problem as an integer linear program takes some time. I'd like to see results faster.

### Task

Write the [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) that when given an integer \$N\ge8\$ (handling lesser numbers is optional) outputs any \$N\$-queens solution that also has the no-3-in-line property. Although it is not proven that solutions exist for all \$N\ge8\$, your code may assume that they do.

The code will be run on my Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 laptop with an 8-core Intel Core i7 processor running Ubuntu 22.10. A program's score is the highest \$N\$ for which a solution is returned in **2 minutes**. You may output in any reasonable format, including graphical formats as above and as a list with the queen indices for each row (the above solution corresponds to the 0-indexed list `[10, 21, 28, 0, 7, 12, 15, 36, 29, 17, 6, 34, 13, 35, 18, 5, 22, 11, 1, 8, 32, 38, 14, 37, 26, 30, 39, 2, 16, 24, 3, 31, 25, 9, 20, 33, 27, 4, 23, 19]`).

I encourage you to post the results for your code on your own machine for my reference.

Comment: Should our code be deterministic?

Comment: @Arnauld There's no restriction – see what works for you – unlike [the other one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258046/110698).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 3 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), N = 565

```python
import math
import random
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import argparse

def line(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    a = y0 - y1
    b = x1 - x0
    gcd = math.gcd(a, b)
    a //= gcd
    b //= gcd
    if a < 0:
        return -a, -b
    elif a == 0:
        if b < 0:
            return 0, -b
        return 0, b
    return a, b

def num_conflicts(l, x, y):
    lines = {(1,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(0,1)}
    n = 0
    for x1, y1 in enumerate(l):
        if x1 == x: continue
        l1 = line(x, y, x1, y1)
        if l1 in lines:
            n += 1
        else:
            lines.add(l1)
    return n

def greedy(n):
    l = []
    for x in range(n):
        z = [num_conflicts(l, x, y) for y in range(n)]
        v = min(z)
        y = random.choice([y for y, k in enumerate(z) if k == v])
        l.append(y)
    return l

def fix_row(n, l, x):
    y0 = l[x]
    nc = num_conflicts(l, x, y0)
    if nc == 0: return 1
    z = [num_conflicts(l, x, y) if y != y0 else nc for y in range(n)]
    v = min(z)
    options = [y for y, k in enumerate(z) if k == v]
    if options == [y0]: return -1
    y = random.choice(options)
    l[x] = y

def solve(t):
    s, n = t
    random.seed(s)
    l = greedy(n)
    for i in range(3*n):
        outcomes = {fix_row(n, l, x) for x in range(n)}
        if outcomes == {1}:
            return l
        if None not in outcomes:
            break

def full(n):
    return next(filter(None, map(solve, enumerate(itertools.repeat(n)))))

def full_mp(n, p):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(p) as p:
        return next(filter(None, p.imap_unordered(solve, enumerate(itertools.repeat(n)))))

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog = "queensthree",
        description = "Finds solution for the no-three-in-a-line n-queens problem"
    )
    parser.add_argument('n', help='number of rows/columns', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-j', default=1, help='number of processes to use (defaults to 1)', type=int)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.j > 1:
        l = full_mp(args.n, args.j)
    else:
        l = full(args.n)
    print(all(num_conflicts(l, x, l[x]) == 0 for x in range(args.n)))
    print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Try it online! (N=327)](https://tio.run/##lVXBbts4EL37K7i5mGolxWoOBYK6wF72uOg9CARaom02FMmSVGplkW/3zpCULMXZYivAljmceZx58zg2gz9qdVeYwQzns@iMtp50zB9X6bdlqtXduOp66YWxuuHOCXUYzcJz67WWbjQwezDMOr5atXxPpFCcnjY5GeBzquBdZfcrAg8jWzCSAixhvYP1qYL1aRPWh6YFC@ZTwk/KcrLLUuDt7Ra3U9h8Jfaw/YVs4hH4WO57q0gB8cUuWLkMXtvt3A1Mu2XgLHgzxS6N0ZbWmGCsWfVd3Wi1l6LxjkqoG8pOVSMfDur6h1Z5leXwXcTXBr43YHoNbgpcIg17bRNvRCjCAZtb5jmV2SJ5YA4KOt0TONgL1fNpU8JOagOgTE2YB8uAHVJb1q/Ixy2pJhOXji8dQkzJ2pbKBJnYUJGKg@W8Hagaq4dUHh4vdeGxoLIDnzzweUGv90kMYcM87HEKe0a5CEVfLrUNYIoqLpujFg2nD0OEyMnTks@XDJl4QhafHy8IsmTGcNXSYVGejOXtxam2@idVOcEMUw2gamD84RRTUw2s3q1mk42aRR@U4wgfKf8VDxA0kD/CDcKuIMJ/UPOGFm280Aol@P@oGFOc4jBw8zilWsRcr5lOAfFUZAPve6TNafnMqU90uTzI3Ud@I4YD2dAxFjYnHU3aEZdK7z7M1aN73@guXrK3/blW3ev8HlxCIbZ6fXcWyHnA31oB9doj4hi8jNpZzp6SWHopJ52P14SfPN0LCUOUIlgOA8/QwE8@68g0ZEvLDWceYPC54NadwSJNQv8p/PHtwC6/AQA1GWGOmKv5eJ2IKQXkUvdK25ZbbMdvZdUx0FxKJ/wfWGjI@N9Q/mkPgKL8t7BDp2wg3QP43fzoOVfOH6HtN/m023LXWBF0hU5/CdU6FFMfLNhbf8R@FCGwEKpgBU4ooooIiPg7ybubAJnNksMZVrOUFV2rdU6OXJrtGqrdQe56T0BI7raB0zrlYNsPhm@F8r9AKb6DH5DBoBPb6hoxNQcE5zXp4RbT5BwMVbY4Jf732QMKO50WXnieo9MowVX5nXwl1aXHeINGlYR9kEr0y1bXc330Tq6pPgtJUIYKfmcg4fXOwgh7e8MSRjZHkVAMZFrXinW8rjFuXdcomLpexzyies7n892nz/8C)

Uses the [Min-conflicts algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-conflicts_algorithm). The gist of the algorithm is to start with a random arrangement of the queens, and repeat the step of choosing a random queen that is in conflict (in check or in a line with two other queens), and move it to a square in the same row with the least conflicts. After a number of steps, if a solution hasn't been found, start over with a different random arrangement.

Because of how the algorithm works, it occasionally gets lucky and finds a solution on the first try (which is what happened with N=565, the previous solution that could be found in 2 minutes was for N=532).

Answer (score 6):

## [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/), N = 70

```
int: n;

array [1..n] of var 1..n: q;

predicate 
    noattack(int: i, int: j, var int: qi, var int: qj) =
    qi     != qj     /\
    qi + i != qj + j /\
    qi - i != qj - j;

constraint
    forall (i in 1..n, j in i+1..n) (
        noattack(i, j, q[i], q[j])
    );

predicate
    no3inline(int: i, int: j, int: k, var int: qi, var int: qj, var int: qk) =
    i * (qk - qj) + j * (qi - qk) + k * (qj - qi) != 0;

constraint
    forall (i in 1..n, j in i+1..n, k in j+1..n) (
        no3inline(i, j, k, q[i], q[j], q[k])
    );

solve :: int_search(q, first_fail, indomain_random)
    satisfy;
```

Adapted from https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-benchmarks/blob/master/queens/queens.mzn.

Solution for \$N = 70\$ in less than 9s on i5-6300U.

It is worth noting that the time required does not always increase when increasing \$N\$. For example, for \$N = 69\$, 2 minutes were not enough.

---

The goal of this answer is not to show off my skills, but the power of MiniZinc and [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) in general.

Comment: How does this compare to Prolog?

Comment: @Jonah
I've never used standard Prolog, but besides minizinc I'm familiar with 'Answer set programming' (ASP), which is roughly a superset of Prolog. From my personal experience, sometimes it is easier to model a problem in minizinc, sometimes in ASP. Sometimes you get a faster solution using minizinc, sometimes using an ASP solver.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), N=20

N=20 in less than a min on my old laptop

```
queens=20;
put[n_,m_,q_]:=(pl={n,m};s[[n,m]]="X";{i,j}=pl;
While[i>1&&j>1,i--;j--;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[i<q&&j<q,i++;j++;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[i<q&&j>1,i++;j--;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[i>1&&j<q,i--;j++;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[i<q,i++;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[i>1,i--;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[j<q,j++;s[[i,j]]++];
{i,j}=pl;
While[j>1,j--;s[[i,j]]++];)


While[(t=0;
qu=queens;
While[t!=qu,s=Table[0,{i,qu},{j,qu}];
put[RandomInteger[{1,qu}],RandomInteger[{1,qu}],qu];
t=1;
While[!FreeQ[s,0],
pos=Position[s,0];
put[First@#,Last@#,qu]&[RandomChoice@pos];t++];];
posi=Position[s,"X"];
Select[(Last@#/First@#&[First@Differences[#]])&/@#&/@(Partition[#,2,1]&/@Subsets[posi,{3}]),SameQ@@#&])!={}]


s=s/. a_/;IntegerQ@a:>".";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLfa8IwEMff@1f4A4rF09oN9mCMFDYGgz3oHGwQgkQXZ4ptbZM@lf7t3aVWGNuYPoQjd9/7fHNJYmH2MhZGbUWdFVImmgZ3pD4WhiVriNeQrfmUDo4HWiYQV0QzhpFz2nvvkVJBVNHjgThve3WQTM0D143mAajRiES4UI0SzodDTpxf6lmG6lkGajgkEa4r1JZt1RfZzUks257kCnaDvYRsaP@KrOVFOzvFzwk8x2mrA0MnxMkKenqOc5PpYgI0fRUb3E0AoVlRQRnZgCb2xV5E8pHGT4mRnzJnZdCU4O9sVmCTocGZ333MpVwyDRMOzjHVdJFqZVSaNKkT/1Hl2oR9eBZNQITbet7vU7WVIfZxYuw8tgMB3yn4YzC7kge5NWxwYvgt0m3ZD2q3k7lMtlKzPuee62PNDwcLkZsTpw83EHDMrYqNlkYzawPlbcU9WIlYLkPs4F6XlhXHO9VU@@OOWPukvYBlKKbz3rhH6kWuEtPxQ13XXw)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, N=128

Adapted from [@gsitcia's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258854/110802)

[Try it online!(N=128)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c78b3818766bbd155bb3e8d4db99dbf5)

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
// use std::env;
use std::iter;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use rand::rngs::StdRng;

fn gcd(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if b == 0 {
        a.abs()
    } else {
        gcd(b, a % b)
    }
}

fn line(x0: usize, y0: usize, x1: usize, y1: usize) -> (i32, i32) {
    let mut a = (y0 as i32) - (y1 as i32);
    let mut b = (x1 as i32) - (x0 as i32);
    let gcd_val = gcd(a, b);
    a /= gcd_val;
    b /= gcd_val;
    if a < 0 {
        (-a, -b)
    } else if a == 0 {
        if b < 0 {
            (0, -b)
        } else {
            (0, b)
        }
    } else {
        (a, b)
    }
}

fn num_conflicts(l: &[usize], x: usize, y: usize) -> usize {
    let mut lines = HashSet::new();
    let mut n = 0;
    for (x1, &y1) in l.iter().enumerate() {
        if x1 == x {
            continue;
        }
        let l1 = line(x, y, x1, y1);
        if lines.contains(&l1) {
            n += 1;
        } else {
            lines.insert(l1);
        }
    }
    n
}

fn greedy(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut l = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    for x in 0..n {
        let z: Vec<usize> = (0..n).map(|y| num_conflicts(&l, x, y)).collect();
        let v = *z.iter().min().unwrap();
        let options: Vec<usize> = z
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter_map(|(y, &k)| if k == v { Some(y) } else { None })
            .collect();
        let y = options[rand::random::<usize>() % options.len()];
        l.push(y);
    }
    l
}

fn fix_row(n: usize, l: &mut [usize], x: usize) -> Option<bool> {
    let y0 = l[x];
    let nc = num_conflicts(l, x, y0);
    if nc == 0 {
        return Some(true);
    }
    let z: Vec<usize> = (0..n).map(|y| if y != y0 { num_conflicts(l, x, y) } else { nc }).collect();
    let v = *z.iter().min().unwrap();
    let options: Vec<usize> = z.iter().enumerate().filter_map(|(y, &k)| if k == v { Some(y) } else { None }).collect();
    if options == [y0] {
        return Some(false);
    }
    let y = options[rand::random::<usize>() % options.len()];
    l[x] = y;
    None
}

fn solve(t: (usize, usize)) -> Option<Vec<usize>> {
    let (s, n) = t;
    let _rng: StdRng = rand::SeedableRng::seed_from_u64(s as u64);
    let mut l = greedy(n);
    for _ in 0..3 * n {
        let outcomes: HashSet<Option<bool>> = (0..n).map(|x| fix_row(n, &mut l, x)).collect();
        let all_true = outcomes.iter().all(|outcome| outcome == &Some(true));
        if all_true {
            return Some(l);
        }
        if !outcomes.contains(&None) {
            break;
        }
    }
    None
}

fn full(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    iter::repeat(n)
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(solve)
        .next()
        .unwrap()
}

fn full_mp(n: usize, p: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let tasks = iter::repeat(n).take(p).enumerate();
    for task in tasks {
        let tx = tx.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let result = solve(task);
            if let Some(solution) = result {
                tx.send(solution).unwrap();
            }
        });
    }
    rx.recv().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    // let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    // if args.len() < 2 {
    //     eprintln!("Usage: {} n [-j processes]", args[0]);
    //     std::process::exit(1);
    // }
    // let n: usize = args[1].parse().expect("n must be an integer");
    // let processes: usize = if args.len() >= 4 && args[2] == "-j" {
    //     args[3].parse().expect("processes must be an integer")
    // } else {
    //     1
    // };

    
    let n: usize = 128;
    let processes: usize =1;
    let l = if processes > 1 {
        full_mp(n, processes)
    } else {
        full(n)
    };

    println!(
        "{}",
        l.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .all(|(x, &y)| num_conflicts(&l, x, y) == 0)
    );
    println!("{:?}", l);
}
```